# how can i create my own model in Stanford Pos tagger?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I want to add new tagged words( local words that is used in our region ) and create a new model. I created a .prop file from command line but how can i create a .tagger file?

When i tried to create such file as mentioned on Stanford website it shows an error like

> "No model specified"

what is the -model argument, is it the corpus? how can i add my new tagged words into that?

How do I train a tagger, then?

The [Stanford site](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) says that:

> You need to start with a .props file which contains options for the
>   tagger to use.  The .props files we used to create the sample taggers
>   are included in the models directory; you can start from whichever one
>   seems closest to the language you want to tag.
>
> For example, to train a new English tagger, start with the left3words
>   tagger props file. To train a tagger for a western language other than
>   English, you can consider the props files for the German or the French
>   taggers, which are included in the full distribution. For languages
>   using a different character set, you can start from the Chinese or
>   Arabic props files. Or you can use the -genprops option to
>   MaxentTagger, and it will write a sample properties file, with
>   documentation, for you to modify. It writes it to stdout, so you'll
>   want to save it to some file by redirecting output (usually with >).
>   The # at the start of the line makes things a comment, so you'll want
>   to delete the # before properties you wish to specify.

Comment: This is the only description i have got from  Stanford website, any one did it before ? help?

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is. We can't tell if you actually have a .props file with something or if you have found errors/problems to be solved. Pasting here text from Stanford website will not bring more help; quite the opposite.

Comment: I want to add  new tagged words( local words that is used in our region ) and want to create new model .i created a .prop  file from command line but how can i create a .tagger file ? when i tried to create such file as mentioned on Stanford website it shows an error like "No model specified" what is the -model argument ,is it the corpus? how can i add my new tagged words into that? .i think the the question is clear now?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two links that can help you, describing step-by-step instructions on how to create (train) your tagger:

1. https://medium.com/@klintcho/training-a-swedish-pos-tagger-for-stanford-corenlp-546e954a8ee7
2. http://www.florianboudin.org/wiki/doku.php?id=nlp_tools_related&DokuWiki=9d6b70b2ee818e600edc0359e3d7d1e8

Please note that inside .conf file you should point to your treebank (that is, real-world sentences parsed in a dependency tree format with POS tags and dependency relations). In this same line you should specify your format:

1. **TEXT**  // represents a tokenized file separated by text
2. **TSV**   // represents a tsv file such as a conll file
3. **TREES** // represents a file in PTB format

In my case, I used a **CoNLL file**, which is a TAB-SEPARATED-VALUES format (TSV). I must confess that couldn't find clear documentation and had to appeal to source code.

My config:

```
model = portuguese.tagger
arch = left3words,naacl2003unknowns,allwordshapes(-1,1)
trainFile = format=TSV,wordColumn=1,tagColumn=4,C:\\path\\universal-dev.conll
closedClassTagThreshold = 40
curWordMinFeatureThresh = 2
tagSeparator = _
encoding = utf-8   # that's because I based my config on spanish!
iterations = 100
lang = spanish
learnClosedClassTags = false
minFeatureThresh = 2
openClassTags = 
rareWordMinFeatureThresh = 10
rareWordThresh = 5
search = qn
sgml = false
sigmaSquared = 0.0
regL1 = 0.75
tokenize = true
tokenizerOptions = asciiQuotes
verbose = false
verboseResults = false
veryCommonWordThresh = 250
xmlInput = null
outputFormat = slashTags
nthreads = 16
```

Comment: My mistake. Actually, **trainfile** property is well-explained in the [javadocs](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html)

Comment: How many iterations would you recommend??? I currently have it set at 100, but im running training on a very large corpus (about 3 million words) and it has been running for over an hour and is only on iteration 52

Answer (score 1):

The `model` property specifies the file to which the built model will be saved. You can provide any valid path, e.g. `mymodel.tagger`.

You can use this same properties file at test time, and `MaxentTagger` will then load from the specified model file rather than saving to it.

To be clear: your training corpus should be provided with the property `trainFile`. See the tagger properties files included with the Stanford Tagger for examples.